# Need help updating some text repeatedly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, replace

So I have this code in the body of my HTML,

```
<div id="timer">
 <div id="years">## Years</div>
 <div id="months">## Months</div>
 <div id="days">## Days</div>
 <div id="hours">## Hours</div>
 <div id="minutes">## Minutes</div>
 <div id="seconds">## Seconds</div>
 <div id="milliseconds">## Milliseconds</div>
</div>
```

and I would like to replace the "##" with the values of some variables that I have set up, but have them be replaced as the variables change, how would I go about doing this with Javascript?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Which part of the solution is unclear to you?

Comment: I have tried using some js to replace the text but I cant get it to replace the text after its already been changed. Is there a way to replace the text based on the id of the div so that the content dosn't matter it just gets replaced?

Comment: For future reference, if you show your attempts you will get better answers because they will relate directly to your problem and it shows effort on your part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try this

```
var years="12";    
document.getElementById("years").innerHTML=document.getElementById("years").innerHTML.replace("##",years);

var months="11"
document.getElementById("months").innerHTML=document.getElementById("months").innerHTML.replace("##",months);
```

And with the same way for the other elements

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5jGK/)

UPDATE:

For repeatedly you will have to do something like this

```
var seconds=0;
var inner=document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML;
setInterval(function(){

document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=seconds+inner.substring(2);
    seconds+=1;
    },1000);
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/u5jGK/1/)

Comment: well what about after the years has been changed? I want each div's content to be updated as the minutes/seconds/hours/ect change without having to refresh the page

Comment: You will have to change only your var years, months etc. And include this code to an interval

Comment: So basically I should have a setInterval around a separate refreshing function?